# Anchor link not clickable

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, z-index, href

I have a simple blog on wordpress http://heather.stevenspiel.com/ and I'm trying to make the header title to be a link to the homepage. I went into header.php and rewrote the script for that part, but still can't get a link to work.

This is what I re-wrote:

```
<h1>
   <a href="http://heather.stevenspiel.com/" style="cursor:pointer !important;">My Spiel</a>
  <br/>&nbsp;
</h1>
```

I know that the href is being registered because of the css color change.

This is what the previous code was:

```
    <h1>
        <?php
            if ($balloons_option['balloons_site-title_line1'] == '' && $balloons_option['balloons_site-title_line2'] == '') { ?>
            This is a<br />
            WordPress theme
        <?php } else {
            echo $balloons_option['balloons_site-title_line1']; ?><br />
            <?php echo $balloons_option['balloons_site-title_line2'];       
        } ?>
    </h1>
```

I originally tried putting the href outside the h1, but still no luck.

Is there some buried Wordpress setting that disables a clickable title? Or is there some javascript that I should be looking out for that is disabling it?

I should also note the css for the header contains a z-index. I read somewhere that it might be effected by that:

```
#header .content {
line-height: 18px;
margin: 0;
z-index: 4;
}
```

If the z-index is effecting it, why is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change z-index property on `line 37` of layout.css to

```
#header h1 {
position: relative;
z-index: 10; /* Was 2 */
}
```

Your `.entry` (`z-index:4`) div goes vertically from top to bottom covering your `#header` with a higher `z-index` than your h1 z-index `(2)`. So your h1/Anchor wsa unclickable because it was "under" another div.

Comment: Glad that made sense! haha

Comment: This answer also holds true if the parent div of the a tag is behind another element.  Bring the parent div forward using z-index to get the a tag clickable again.

Comment: bro you just saved from my 4hrs of debugging